# How can I compare two string values in SQL?

Tags: sql

The problem statement is as mentioned below:
`When max_pos> 4 and max_neg is >1` 
then find out the name of rollercoaster 
where intensity_level  is greater than  excitement_level.

Here, the intensity_level and excitement_level are string values like high, very high etc.  How can I compare them?

Comment: share sample input and output

Comment: Provide full dictionary of possible values for intensity and excitement levels.

Comment: better to have this values like `high, very high etc` in separate table (ID, Value) and create relation with  `rollercoaster` table by this table ID

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE` expression to map value for your `intensity_level` and `excitement_level`, then compare them

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE 
    max_pos> 4 
    AND max_neg >1
    AND
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN intensity_level = 'high' THEN 0
            WHEN intensity_level = 'very high' THEN 1
            WHEN intensity_level = 'ultra high' THEN 2
        END 
        > 
        CASE 
            WHEN excitement_level = 'high' THEN 0
            WHEN excitement_level = 'very high' THEN 1
            WHEN excitement_level = 'ultra high' THEN 2
        END
    );
```

Comment: case _expression_ (it returns a value.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table that contains intensity_level and excitement_level for each rollercoaster as integers and an ID that links them to your main table

Answer (score 0):

try using DECODE. DECODE high, very high values with a number and alias and then select all from this result set, then compare the aliases

Answer (score 0):

Here My solution using the function
Just assign a integer value to the string and then compare the integer value.

```
CREATE function Weight(tag VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE v INT;
IF tag='High' THEN
SET v=1;
END IF;
IF tag='Very High' THEN
SET v=2;
END IF;
RETURN v;
END;|
```

Then use the query

```
Select *
From tablename
Where max_pos> 4 
AND max_neg is >1
AND Weight(intensity_level)>Weight(excitement_level);
```

The Weight function above maybe not work in SQL, I used MySQL so change accordingly.